# Focusing a textbox using javascript in a google-chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, textbox, setfocus

How do you focus a textbox in a google-chrome extension? I have tried this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFocus()
{
     document.getElementById("Target").focus();
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="setFocus()">

<div style="float:left">
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" id="mytable" style="float:left;">

<tbody><tr><td>Target:</td> <td><input type="text" name="Target" size="25" value="" /></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I found this code on multiple code forum websites, so I am not sure if the javascript is not working or if chrome prevents it from running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getElementById()`, but in your example `Target` is the `name` attribute, not the `ID`.

Add `id="Target"`, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Target" name="Target" size="25" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code you gave doesn't work is because your input doesn't have an ID of "target", it only has a name. Add the correct ID and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you want to get an element by ID, when you don't have one.  You must add `id="Target"` to the input.